# Why does gzip_disable make nginx crash?

Tags: nginx, gzip

I've inspired my nginx configuration file from [defunkt's conf file for unicorn](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/examples/nginx.conf) but it seems that the line `gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";` makes everything crash. I get the error that this site is temporarily unavailable (served from `nginx/html/50x.html`). Commenting out the line makes everything work again, fiddling with the regexp doesn't change a thing.

I'm running nginx v.1.0.10 and ubuntu 11.10.

Any idea?

Comment: There has never been an Nginx 1.0.10. Perhaps you meant 1.0.1. If so, any particular reason why you are running such an old version ... considering there have been over 100 bug fixes since?

Comment: While I would also suggest updating, the 1.0 line actually made it to 1.0.15 before becoming unmaintained: http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES-1.0

Comment: I'm not sure how I ended up with such an old version, my server was setup only 6 months ago. It works now so all is fine, I'll update it when I have some spare time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's already about few years when Nginx API changed for this directive, it should be:

```
gzip_disable              "msie6";
```

Full stack Nginx+Unicorn optimized configuration can be found [on the gist](https://gist.github.com/3052776).

Comment: Thanks using "msie6" does work! I'm actually surprised, I would have thought that, since it's a regexp, you could give it any value; it doesn't matter if it doesn't match anything, it's just pretty pointless. Well..

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted this to be here

`gzip_disable    "msie6";` is mentioned in official nginx docs here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_disable as a special mask for regex `MSIE [4-6]\`, but works faster.